# android how to kill a process or an app and detect some app restart again

Tags: android

Recently,When I use some security applications,I find those application can kill others applications,but when I read api,the android just support some api to kill application itself,it doesn't support any other api directly to kill any process or application in phone.So how those security applications can kill other applications?Do those guys use some functions like linux "kill" system call?And I also find those security applications can clean RAM,Do they clean memory by killing app?The last question is some application can start itself when phone started,those some security applications can avoid this situation happening?But as I known,those applications register bootcompletion broadcastreceiver,so how security applications make those receiver disable?I hope someone who has experience on those areas can help me solve these questions,thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can kill some processes with:

```
   public void killSelf(Context context) {
            ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context
                            .getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            am.killBackgroundProcesses(getPackageName());

            if (mServiceList != null) {
                    for (RunningServiceInfo service : mServiceList) {
                            context.stopService(new Intent().setComponent(service.service));
                    }
            }
    }
```

More detail, you can see my personal project about TaskManager,here is source code:
 http://code.google.com/p/my-test-project-lion/